# 4 monitors dual graphics card

Tags: graphics, xorg

I've a new PC at work, which, for some reason, won't work with my nvidia quadro gfx card.

The PC has on board gfx Witt an Intel based chip set that supports dual monitors. I can get a third screen running via the quadro, with nouveau, but not the fourth (the fourth is detected, but won't turn on, xrandr throws an error)

If I run three screens, I get massive tearing on the third display.

If I install the nvidia drivers, I can't get a graphical environment.

Is there a gfx card that would allow me to run 4 monitors? (2 on internal, 2 on external) using nouveau?